# Access Lazy Module's ActivatedRoute angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I need to access the information of the ActivatedRouter of the module loaded lazy in an X component

```
//Lazy 
{
   "path":"root-lazy",
   "children":[
      {
         "path":"parent-1",
         "children":[
            {
               "path":"child",
               "component":"ChildComponent"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I can access simply by putting **route.parent.parent**, but how to do when I don't know how many levels to get to the root of the deferred module?

the modules have something like this, **route.root**, which refers to the AppComponent and the root module, I need something like this, **route.lazy**, which refers to the lazy module